# Minimal cover FD

Tags: database-normalization, functional-dependencies

I have the following exercise text:

> Stack Overflow is a community where users (US), with a specific number of years of experience (Ye), can ask questions and give answers. Based on the given answers, each user earns a reputation (Re) and a badge (Ba), a sort of medal (e.g., bronze, silver and gold badge). The number of years of experience starts from the registration date (Da) on Stack Overflow. Each user can gain some money (Mo) by answering a question. Please note that the description above is not referring to the real Stack Overflow, but it’s useful to define the following exercise. The following FDs are satisfied:
>
> 1. Each user has a specific number of years of experience and a specific badge
> 2. The years of experience uniquely determine the user’s reputation and the amount of money for each answer
> 3. For each user and for each reputation is defined a unique badge
> 4. The registration date determines a single value of years of experience
> 5. Each user earns a specific amount of money for each answer

The FDs I defined are the following ones:

1. YeBa -> US
2. Ye -> ReMo
3. Ba -> USRe
4. Da -> Ye
5. Mo -> US

I'm not sure about the third one and the last one. For the third one I don't know if it is correct the one I wrote, or there must be two FDs (Ba -> US, Ba -> Re). For the last one I'm not sure how to represent it, because the sentence doesn't tell exactly what I wrote, and I think it is wrong because it asks me to apply the minimal cover and with these FDs it is not possible.

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--not all terms/notations are standard & we don't know exactly what algorithm/method you are following & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an algorithm allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went right or wrong & we don't want to rewrite your reference. [ask] Ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question re the 1st place you are stuck. PS What is the assignment question? What is your question?

Comment: The assignment language for 3 is not clear. Say how you choose to reasonably interpret it, or ways you think are reasonable to interpret it. When an assignment is not clear, prepare & speak to your teacher. PS In your last sentence it seems like you might be trying to say something that includes that you have been given a cover as answer; but like with most of your post, it's not clear. PS Always use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Comment: I'm sorry. My question is if the 5th FD I wrote is correct (Mo -> US). The idea we use to create the FDs is put to the right the "fields" that depends on the left. Ex. The year and the badge defines the user, or in other words, the user is identified by the year and the badge.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please act on everything in my earlier comments. PS You still don't say why those FDs arise from the given English. Give your interpretation of the unclear bullets in your own clearer English where you are not sure. PS "earns a specific amount of money" suggests ...->{Mo}. Suggest you try some example data to help you understand the bullets. PS When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A functional dependency `X → Y` expresses the fact that values of the set of attributes `Y` are determined in a unique way from the values of the set of attributes `X`. In other words, for each combination of `X` values there is a unique, specific combination of values of `Y`.

Let's examine the facts described in the exercise.

> 1. Each user has a specific number of years of experience and a specific badge

You have represented this fact with the dependency:

> 1. Ye Ba → US

but this is exactly the opposite. With the above FD, in fact, you are saying that given a number of years of experience and a certain badge, there is only a user with such years and badge, but in the reality it is possible  that different users have the same years of experience and badge. The fact specified by the sentence can instead be expressed by the FD:

```
1. US → Ye Ba
```

that is, each user determines (has uniquely) a number of years of experience and a badge.

Let see the other facts:

> 2. The years of experience uniquely determine the user’s reputation and the amount of money for each answer

```
2. Ye → Re Mo
```

(this is correct)

> 3. For each user and for each reputation is defined a unique badge

This is somewhat ambiguous, as pointed in a comment, in the sense that the badge is probably determined by the reputation only, but if we follow the specification and write the FD corresponding to it, we can write:

```
3. US Re → Ba
```

(not the viceversa), and this will be simplified when we will compute a minimal cover.

> 4. The registration date determines a single value of years of experience

```
4. Re → Ye
```

(correct)

> 5. Each user earns a specific amount of money for each answer

```
5. US → Mo
```

again, there is a certain, specific, amount of money earned by a user (and not the viceversa, since that would mean that for a certain amount of money earned, only a single user can earn it).

So we have now the dependencies:

```
US → Ye Ba
Ye → Re Mo
US Re → Ba
Re → Ye
US → Mo
```

and we can compute a minimal cover from it. Here is a possible computation (note that it is *always* possible to compute a minimal cover from *any* set of dependencies).

First we transform the dependencies with a single attribute on the right:

```
Re US → Ba
Re → Ye
US → Ba
US → Ye
US → Mo
Ye → Mo
Ye → Re
```

In `Re US → Ba`, `Re` is extraneous since `{US}+ = (Ba Mo Re US Ye)`. So we replace this dependency with `US → Ba` (which is already present).

From the remaining dependencies, we can now remove the redundant dependency:

```
US → Mo
```

This is because we have US → Ye and Ye → Mo.

So, the final set of dependencies (a minimal cover) is:

```
Re → Ye
US → Ba
US → Ye
Ye → Mo
Ye → Re
```

Comment: Why US -> Ba and US -> Mo are redundant?

Comment: @ElenaFranchini, I edited the answer to reply to your comment. US -> Ba is already present, while US -> Mo is redundant because of the transitivity rule applied to US -> Ye and Ye -> Mo.